# Why does not parallax work if I put it inside the div with the ng-repeat directive of angular?

Tags: angularjs, materialize

When I put the parallax container line out of this div the image is displayed but if I put it inside the ng-repeat the space goes blank. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="col" data-ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">
    <div class="col s12 center">
        <h4>{{exercise.title}}</h4>
        <div class="left-align light">
            <h5 class="left-align">
                {{exercise.content}}
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax">
            <img data-ng-src="{{exercise.img}}" alt="background image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```